# Swift subclasses complex subtype

Tags: ios, swift, inheritance, enums, unions

I have this design problem in Swift. Here is my root class and it's subclasses:

```
enum VisualItemType {
    case video, picture, text,...
}

class VisualItem {

   public var itemType: VisualItemType
   ...
}

class PictureItem:VisualItem {
   private var subItems:[PictureItem OR TextItem But NOT VideoItem]? //Overlay of picture can be picture or text but not video
}

class VideoItem: VisualItem {
   private var subItems:[VisualItem]? //Overlay of video can be any type of visual item

}
```

How do I cleanly implement subItems of PictureItem in Swift without creating a new enum of subtypes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that by introducing a new protocol that only `TextItem` and `PictureItem` will conform:

```
protocol PictureOverlayable: VisualItem {}

class TextItem: VisualItem, PictureOverlayable {}

class PictureItem: VisualItem, PictureOverlayable {
   private var subItems: [PictureOverlayable]?
}
```